# Improving speed when using sapply with Rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to R and have just learned rvest. I'm trying to web scrape this website https://www.displayspecifications.com/en

I'm trying to take the specification of every TV model in each brand.

What I’m trying to do is:

1. Go to the brand page (eg: LG) and scrape the name of every model to use as `name` column
2. Scrape the link of every model to use the URL to scrape the specification
3. Create a function to scrape the specific line for the specification that I want inside each model URL
4. Run the function using `sapply` to retrieve the specification of every tv model for the `specs` column

I used selector gadget to help me identify the element I'm trying to capture. That works fine.

```
#step 1

link = "https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/brand/a1025"
page = read_html(link)
name = page %>%
  html_nodes(".model-listing-container-80 a") %>%
  html_text()

#step 2

model_links = page %>%
  html_nodes(".model-listing-container-80 a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Then I tried to create a function that will scrape the specs across all model URLs. The function works fine with just one URL.

```
#step 3

get_specs = function(model_link) {
  model_page  = read_html(model_link)  
  model_specs = model_page %>%
    html_nodes('[property="og:description"]') %>%
    html_attr('content') 
  return(model_specs)
}
```

It works fine if I just use it for one model url. Which will gives me the details that I wanted like this

```
[1] "Specifications of LG 43NANO776QA. Display: 42.5 in, VA, Direct LED, 3840 x 2160 pixels, Viewing angles (H/V): 178 ° / 178 °, Refresh rate: 50 Hz / 60 Hz, TV tuner: Analog (NTSC/PAL/SECAM), DVB-C, DVB-S2, DVB-T, DVB-T2, DVB-S, Cores: 4, Dimensions: 967 x 564 x 57.7 mm, Weight: 9.2 kg. LG 43NANO776QA is also known as LG 43NANO779QA, LG 43NANO773QA."
```

Since I need to retrieve the specs of all models, I use `sapply`:

```
#step 4

specs = sapply(model_links, FUN = get_specs)
```

The problem is in step 4. It takes forever and I'm not even sure whether it will generate an output. By forever I mean I left the computer overnight and RStudio is still running with no output. And I tried to run again for 4 hours today and decided to stop it. Maybe something is wrong with the code? Is there an alternative to `sapply`?

Comment: Each url in `model_links` is repeated once. Use `unique(model_links)` to only retain unique urls. I used `specs = sapply(head(model_links), FUN = get_specs)` and was able to obtain results.

Comment: Probably run the loop for only a handful of links to see what part is taking long (using Profiler). On my end it's the `read_html` part that takes the maximum time which might be hard to reduce and depend on your internet connection. Probably should also put a print statement inside to keep track of progress (and in case it fails/takes too long on some particular URL)

Comment: Oh, can I include unique in sapply like `specs = sapply(unique(model_links), FUN = get_specs)` or it should be an intermediary step before sapply? `model_links <- unique(model_links)`

Comment: It would be efficient if it would be an  intermediary step and rather than including in `sapply`.

Comment: Apart from your script, there *might* be server-side measures to throttle or block mass requests from the same client (=your machine). If all else fails, you might try to lower your requests' cadence, e.g. with `Sys.wait()`.

Comment: I used `unique(model_links)` and manage to retrieve output after 2 hours. I'm not sure how to use profiling and I can't find the documentation for `Sys.wait()`. `Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
  no methods for ‘Sys.wait’ and no documentation for it as a function`

Comment: I can confirm that indeed, the website blocks the IP of users who are a bit too prolific with the scraping. :-) I think the function that you need is `Sys.sleep()`. You can give it a number of seconds to wait until the next request. In cases where websites allow you to do many request one thing you can do is parallelizing your code. But remember to be nice to people and their servers as well... 
```future::plan('multisession', workers = 12)
result <- furrr::future_map_chr(unique(model_links), get_specs) ```

Comment: Oh yeah, I noticed this week that I can't scrape the website anymore. `read_html` can no longer read the link. Thank you for the tips, will look into parallelizing.

Comment: Strange! I was able to scrape the website. Lets hope it would be a temporary ban or try using VPN.